# What is the purpose of the parameter passed to: IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder?

Tags: c#, network-programming, endianness

I am looking at some code, which someone else has written and looks like this:

```
protected override void CloseAndSend(BinaryWriter request, uint lengthPos)
{
request.Seek((int)lengthPos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
request.Write(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder((int)(request.BaseStream.Length - lengthPos - sizeof(int))));

//more code here.
}
```

I understand that IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder ensures that the appropriate endianness is used, however what is the purpose of the arguement i.e. `(int)(request.BaseStream.Length - lengthPos - sizeof(int)))`? I have read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.hosttonetworkorder?view=netcore-3.1.  I can't find any examples and hence the reason for the question.  I have spent two hours Googling it.

**Update**

Here is the code, which populates the BinaryWriter (in correct order):

```
    byte EOL = 0;
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream());
        writer.Write(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("API"));
        writer.Write(EOL);
        writer.Write((int)0);
        writer.Write(UTF8Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("v100..155"));
        //request.BaseStream.Length - lengthPos - sizeof(int)=9
        //writer.BaseStream.Length=17
```

Comment: It's the number being converted to network order. You want to write a number in binary form, but you don't know whether currently big endian or little endian being used, so you use this method to convert to network order (big endian) if necessary.

Comment: @Evk, thanks.  Wouldn't you have to convert the entire stream?

Comment: Looks like difference is Big Endian verses Little Endian.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.hosttonetworkorder?view=netcore-3.1.  It is in the remarks on the link (or your link).

Comment: @jdweng, I posted that link in my question.  Do you know of any scenarios where you would not convert the entire stream?

Comment: Yes if the data is not all int32 (4 byte data).

Comment: @jdweng, are you able to provide an example of where you would only convert part of a stream in an answer?

Comment: You are sending binary data.  Is the data 1 byte, 2, byte, 4 byte, or 8 byte, or combination?  The HostNetworkOrder only works when all the data is 4 byte.

Comment: @jdweng, I have posted an update.  Does that help clarify?

Comment: You are writing strings to a binary writer which  ae either one or two bytes so you do not need to use HostToNetworkOrder.  HostToNetworkOrder is meant for writing int32 to a binary writer.

Comment: @jdweng, apologies again - there was another mistake in my update. Could you have a look again?

Comment: You still are writing strings which are not int32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you need to pass a short\int\long number over the wire. Over the wire you can only pass binary data, and such number takes more than 1 byte to represent. Then there is a problem - one can read multiple bytes either from left to right, or right to left, and results will be different. That means protocol should specify this, or if unspecified - there should be a convention. Such convention exists for network protocols and big endian is used if not stated otherwise.

Now, `BinaryWriter` always uses endianess of current architecture (you can check it via `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` for example). What if your current arcitecture is little endian and you need to write a number (such as following message length which is common in TCP protocols) over the wire? Say the length is 1, and amount of bytes reserved for this length is 2 (so, overall length is `short`). If you just do

```
request.Write(length)
```

on little endian architecture, then two bytes 01 - 00 are written over the wire. However, 01 - 00 bytes in big endian represent completely different number - 256. The consumer on the other end of the wire, if he assumes big endian as it should - will read two bytes, and interpret them as completely different message length.

So to avoid that - you convert said number to big endian if necessary:

```
request.Write(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(length))
```

If you are on little endian `HostToNetworkOrder` will convert short 1 to 256, and then `BinaryWriter` which also uses little endian in this case will write bytes 00 - 01 (representation of 256 in little endian). If you are on big endian then `HostToNetworkOrder` will return 1 back, and `BinaryWriter` will again write the same 00 - 01 bytes over the wire, ensuring consistent representation.

To follow up your update:

The code in question writes string "API" in UTF-8 (3 bytes), then some EOL byte (now we have 4 bytes) and then reserves 4 bytes by writing zero integer. It proceeds to write another stuff and then returns back to the position of this reserved 4-byte integer (containing all zero bytes). It then calculates length of the stuff following that 4-byte integer ("v100..155" and so on) and writes this length into reserved position. In such quite a weird way it just writes the length of the following data, the usual thing in most TCP protocols.

If that's the whole code then simple way to do the same is just:

```
    byte EOL = 0;
    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream());
    writer.Write(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("API"));
    writer.Write(EOL);
    var data = UTF8Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("v100..155");
    writer.Write(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(data.Length));
    writer.Write(data);
```

Comment: Thanks.  As I said in the question I understand the concept of endianess.  What I don't understand is why only part of the stream appears to be converted (see the arguement passed to: IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder.  Do you know of any scenarios were you would not convert the entire stream?

Comment: @w0051977 endianess does not apply to the whole stream, only to pieces of data encoded in it. Suppose you pass 3 two-byte numbers over the wire. Then under one endianess that will be `a-b-c-d-e-f`, while under another: `b-a-d-c-f-e`, it will never be `f-e-d-c-b-a`. In this case, a _number_ is being converted (number being the result of `(int)(request.BaseStream.Length - lengthPos - sizeof(int))`) and this number is then written to the `BinaryWriter`. If the result of that expression is say `10` then number 10 is being written to BinaryWriter, ensuring appropriate endianess.

Comment: are you able to provide an example of where you would only convert part of a stream in your answer?

Comment: @w0051977 code in your question does not convert anything. It seeks to specified position in stream and writes a specific number there, that's it. So I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Not really. It writes some strings to the stream, then returns back to position 4 and writes a number `(request.BaseStream.Length - lengthPos - sizeof(int)` there, overwriting what was there before (if anything). No idea what that all means.

Comment: Apologies - there was a mistake in my update. Could you have a look again?

Comment: You are still writing the strings "API" and "v100..155".  These are not int32 numbers.

Comment: @jdweng, there are int32 numbers also added though?

Comment: So you have a mixture of strings (one or two  bytes) and int32 so like I said earlier when you have mixtures you cannot use HostToNetworkOrder.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you clarify what you mean by: "the usual thing in most TCP protocols".

Comment: @w0051977 TCP protocol is not packet based, it's just a stream of bytes, which means when sending data over TCP you cannot just say to the receiving end - "read this packet", there is no such concept. So you must let the other end know how much bytes it needs to read. For that, usually, you first send the length of your data in first say 4 bytes (as an integer). Say I want to send 20 bytes of data. I first send number "20" in binary form in first 4 bytes. The other side reads this 4 bytes, gets "20" and then follows by reading 20 bytes.

Comment: Thanks - that explains it.  I think the EOL (end of line?) might be there to identify the end of the ASCII characters.  Does that sound plausible? Haven't looked at the other side yet.

Comment: @w0051977 Yes, that's probably null terminated string, for the same reasons as above: for strings of unknown length you can folllow them by zero byte to indicate the end of string. For arbitrary binary data (not strings) you cannot do this, because zero byte is perfectly valid inside the data itself